# Deleting object from Array of dictionaries in nsuserdefaults

Tags: ios

I have an array of dictionary saved in userdefaults. The objects saves in dictionaty are viewed in tableview. When delete button of the table view cell is clicked a popup appeapers which confirm whether the user wants to delete or not. On clicking yes it selected object should be deleted from table view as well as userdefaults. 
Please help. 
Any help would be appreciable. 
Thankx in advance.

Comment: You're using `NSUserDefaults` to store data, aren't you?

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Version without animation**

```
// First of all remove it from userDefaults
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"YourArray"] mutableCopy];
[yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourArray forKey:@"YourArray"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];   

// Reload your tableView with a new data
self.tableData = yourArray;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

**Extended Version without animation**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // First of all remove it from userDefaults
    NSMutableArray *yourArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"YourArray"] mutableCopy];
    [yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourArray forKey:@"YourArray"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];   

    // Refresh your tableView with a new data
    self.tableData = yourArray;
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: This looks good, but you might consider animating the removing of the specific row using `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` rather than using `reloadData`, which gives no user feedback.

Answer (score -2):

To make changes to the user defaults, use the setObject method.